# Sorting datatables with IP-Adresses and hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My datatable was acting cool and all until I modified integer element of a particular column(with hyperlinks) to IP Adresses. All of a sudden the sorting feature was acting weird.

Before I had something like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['intComparer-asc'] = function (a, b) {
  var m = a.match(/^\<.*\>(\d+)\<.*\>/);
  a = m[1];
  var m = b.match(/^\<.*\>(\d+)\<.*\>/);
  b = m[1];
  var value1 = parseInt(a);
  var value2 = parseInt(b);
  return ((value1 < value2) ? -1 : ((value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['intComparer-desc'] = function (a, b) {
  var m = a.match(/^\<.*\>(\d+)\<.*\>/);
  a = m[1];
  var m = b.match(/^\<.*\>(\d+)\<.*\>/);
  b = m[1];
  var value1 = parseInt(a);
  var value2 = parseInt(b);
  return ((value1 < value2) ? 1 : ((value1 > value2) ? -1 : 0));
};

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tableAsI').dataTable({
            'aoColumnDefs': [
                { 'sType': 'intComparer', 'aTargets': [ 0, 1 ] }
            ]
        });
    }); 
</script>


<table class="table" id="tableAsI">
<thead> <tr class="infoo"> <th>N</th> <th>IP</th> </tr> </thead>
  <tbody>

    <?php
    echo '<tr><td>2</td>';
    echo '<td ><a href="index2.php" title="2">13</a></td>';
    echo'</tr>';
    echo '<tr> <td>4</td>';
    echo '<td ><a href="index4.php" title="4">1</a></td>';
    echo'</tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>1</td>';
    echo '<td ><a href="index1.php" title="1">2</a></td>';
    echo'</tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>3</td>';
    echo '<td ><a href="index3.php" title="3">20</a></td>';
    echo'</tr>';

    ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the sorting works well, but after adding the IP Adresses i have this for example:

```
<td ><a href="index3.php" title="3">100.130.6.109</a></td>
```

and the result is :

```
100.130.6.109
**100.130.6.11**
100.130.6.110
100.130.6.111
```

What i want is this :

```
**100.130.6.11**
100.130.6.109
100.130.6.110
100.130.6.111
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this plugin (or the code from it in the case of extra links support)? https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/ip-address

The plugin uses the code like this:

```
var m = a.split("."), x = "";
```

But, because you also have the hyperlink, with a small help of jQuery, you can easily parse and extract the content of the link. For example:

```
$('<a href="index3.php" title="3">100.130.6.109</a>').html();
```

This will give you `100.130.6.109` exactly. Thus, the small modification to the plugin code would look like this:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "ip-address-pre": function(a) {
        var ip_address = $(a).html();
        var m = ip_address.split("."), x = "";
...
```